# MIssing 'Drush configuration' and 'Php configuration' when running 'Drush status'

Tags: drush

If a run the method 'drush status' in the terminal I see that the values for  'Drush configuration' and 'Php configuration' are missing.

It give me not problem at all. But is this correct?

Look the capture:

I use the free version of MAMP.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues has MAMP installed and that's what his Drush status looks like too.

I'm using the build of Apache built in to OSX and the only difference I see is that the PHP configuration is filled in:

[image: Screenshot]

Like you, neither my colleague or I suffer any problems with these settings missing so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: thanks clive, as you say I'll pay no attention to this.